# How do you say "empanada" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you say "empanada" in Esperanto? I've tried to find a term for it but failed.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empanada):

> An empanada is a type of baked or fried turnover consisting of pastry
>   and filling, common in Latin American and Filipino cultures.

[image: Empanada]

[Image source link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Empanada_-_Stu_Spivack.jpg#/media/File:Empanada_-_Stu_Spivack.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find the exact word for *empanada* but I think ***(fritita) pastopoŝo*** is close enough. According to PIV if the *empanada* is small and the filling is sweet it is named ***dariolo*** and if the filling is meat, fish, etc. ***risolo***.

From PIV:

> **dariol/o** Fritita kukaĵo, speco de pastopoŝo kun, interne, dolĉaĵo.
>
> **risol/o** Pastopoŝeto aŭ bulo, entenanta muelitan viandon, fiŝaĵon aŭ ĉasaĵon, k fritita en graso aŭ oleo.

Comment: There are lots of different kinds of fried turnovers or pasties, so I'm not sure if there is an "exact" translation. A better approach is to use a general term like _pastopoŝo_ like Vidamuzo suggests and then add some description to it, e.g. _latinamerika dolĉa fritita pastopoŝo_, _kornvala bolkuirita pastopoŝo kun fiŝo_ and so on. That way it is more widely understood.